# Need to create a class having only methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have some methods having return type.
I want to create a single class and want to call all methods using that class.

How i create and use it ?

**Is i have to create class of < NSObject >  or Singleton class**

code i want to write in that class :

```
-(NSDictionary *)abc{
     NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
           ca, @"object1", 
           da, @"object2", nil];
    return dict;
}
```

In My `Main` class Suppose `AViewcontroller.m`
I want to call this fuction as

```
NSDictionary *dicreturn=[self abc];
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve?  It looks like you want to know how to create an instance of a class and call methods on that instance, but that is too basic, surely?

Comment: just you have to create singleton class to achieve this  and write all your common methods under that class then access these methods in another class using sharedInstance.

Comment: yes i want to create a class like we create for define all constant.h class ,similiar approach for all method to be call.

Comment: Make all your methods static then you can call your methods whenever required using your class name , you just need to import that common class  , wherever you require

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right - try to use plus sign (class method). Something like:

```
+(NSDictionary *)abc {

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         ca, @"object1", 
                         da, @"object2", nil];

    return dict;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is add a **category** to you ViewController:

**AViewController+myCategory.h**

```
#import "AViewController.h"

@interface AViewController (myCategory)
-(NSDictionary *)abc;
@end
```

**AViewController+myCategory.m**

```
#import "AViewController+myCategory.h"

@implementation AViewController (myCategory)
-(NSDictionary *)abc{

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          ca, @"object1",
                          da, @"object2", nil];

    return dict;
}
@end
```

Then in **AViewConctroller.m** you can call `[self abc];`